# Warning message in R function for Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm doing an R package for Multiple Lineal Regression for a final work in a subject, and I've started calculating Linear Regression coefficients.

```
AjusteLineal <- function(y,x){
   x <- cbind(rep(1,length(x)),x)
   return (solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% (t(x) %*% y))
}

x <- seq(0,30,5)
y <- c(2,1.41,1.05,0.83,0.7,0.62,0.57)
X <- cbind(x,x^2)
X
y

AjusteLineal(y,X)
```

This showed me a warning.

```
[,1]
   1.946904762
x -0.105571429
   0.002038095
Warning message:
  In cbind(rep(1, length(x)), x) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

How can I fix this? I think coefficients are good, but this warning bothers me.

Thanks!

Comment: `length(x)` is the same as `prod(dim(x))` for a matrix, whereas I assume you want `nrow(x)`. I would change `cbind(rep(1,length(x)),x)` to `cbind(1, x)`, as `nrow(x)` will fail for a vector, but `cbind(1, x)` handles both simple and multiple regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about the first line in your function:

```
x <- cbind(rep(1,length(x)),x)
```

This is trying to prepend the column vector `rep(1,length(x))` to the matrix `x`. What will that column vector look like in relation to the matrix `x`? Let's see:

```
str(rep(1, length(X)))
# num [1:14] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
str(X)
# num [1:7, 1:2] 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 0 25 100 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" ""
```

The "length" of a matrix is the number of elements in the matrix; you don't want to prepend a column vector with the length of the product of both matrix dimensions! That's why when you try that operation, you get a warning:

```
cbind(rep(1, length(X)), X)
#         x    
# [1,] 1  0   0
# [2,] 1  5  25
# [3,] 1 10 100
# [4,] 1 15 225
# [5,] 1 20 400
# [6,] 1 25 625
# [7,] 1 30 900
# Warning message:
# In cbind(rep(1, length(X)), X) :
#   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Fortunately we can make use of recycling in `cbind()`, since the column you're prepending only has one value in it:

```
AjusteLineal <- function(y,x){
    # x <- cbind(rep(1,length(x)),x) ## Causes warning
    x <- cbind(1, x)                 ## works just fine
    return (solve(t(x) %*% x) %*% (t(x) %*% y))
}

AjusteLineal(y,X)

#           [,1]
#    1.946904762
# x -0.105571429
#    0.002038095
```